# Int64 can't be converted if store in Realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

I need to save 11 digits number in Realm, for that am using `Int64`.
When am reading it I need to convert it's datatype to `String`

```
let icnStr = employeeObj["icn"] as! String
```

but it is showing following error.

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x186d21c) to 'NSString' (0xefd5e4).
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `String(employeeObj["icn"])`, hope it help, dont downcast it but create `String` instance with value of the Int

Comment: Thanks let icnStr = String(describing: employeeObj["icn"]) worked
But not able to unwrap now.

Comment: You just recreate back the Int from that String, it will work

Comment: I need to use String & it is printing this value
Optional(13421423231)
& when am trying to unwrap it, it is saying
cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type string

Comment: What's the point then if I again convert it to Int64. I need String.

Comment: I mean when you need to use it as Int then just convert back....What do you mean you cant unwrap?? Convert to string like this is perfectly fine, it's not optional, of course you cant unwarp it??

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following otherwise you'll be not able to unwrap it.

Use following code.

```
let icnStr = String(describing: employeeObj["icn"]!)
```

It'll unwrap Optional value, because when it becomes `String` you can't unwrap it. It'll give the following error.

```
cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type string
```